# naked domain heroku with Zerigo

Tags: heroku

Hello there here is my problem.
I've a domain example.com and example.herokuapp.com. It is not recommended by the website to install A records pointing to heroku and this makes the naked domains not possible, so I'm forced to use www.example.com instead of example.com.

I've seen on internet that this is actually possible to do, so far I heard of Zerigo.
Do you have any workaround to that?

Thanks,
n

Comment: Using DNSimple helps you solve that problem with an Alias Record. It keeps updating the A record automatically. https://dnsimple.com/r/bf3442e7fba3fd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you either need to point your A-records for example.com at the Heroku Ips, or better still use DNSimple's ALIAS to do it with a CNAME.

More info here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords